# Uniform checks for different lists with similar items

Tags: c#, collections

my code is exploding, maybe you can help me. My class `Painter` has some lists of some objects:

```
public class Painter
{
    private readonly MyCar[] cars = new MyCar[5];
    private readonly MyHouse[] houses = new MyHouse[6];
    private readonly MyPaper[] papers = new MyPaper[7];
}

public class MyCar
{
    public void Paint(System.Drawing.Color color) { /* ... */ }
}
public class MyHouse
{
    public void Paint(System.Drawing.Color color) { /* ... */ }
}
public class MyPaper
{
    public void Paint(System.Drawing.Color color) { /* ... */ }
}
```

I added a method which allows to paint one of the objects:

```
public class Painter
{
    private readonly MyCar[] cars = new MyCar[5];
    private readonly MyHouse[] houses = new MyHouse[5];
    private readonly MyPaper[] papers = new MyPaper[5];

    public void Paint(ObjectType type, int index, System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ObjectType.Car: this.cars[index].Paint(color); break;
            case ObjectType.House: this.houses[index].Paint(color); break;
            case ObjectType.Paper: this.papers[index].Paint(color); break;
        }
    }

    public enum ObjectType
    {
        Car,
        House,
        Paper
    }
}
```

All reasonable so far, but I want to check if index exceeds the length of the corresponding array.

```
    public bool Paint(ObjectType type, int index, System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ObjectType.Car:
                if (index < this.cars.Length)
                {
                    this.cars[index].Paint(color);
                    return true;
                }

                break;

            case ObjectType.House:
                if (index < this.houses.Length)
                {
                    this.houses[index].Paint(color);
                    return true;
                }

                break;

            case ObjectType.Paper:
                if (index < this.papers.Length)
                {
                    this.papers[index].Paint(color);
                    return true;
                }

                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Furthermore I want to change the meaning of index. If it is zero, then paint all objects of that type, otherwise paint list[index - 1].

```
    public bool Paint(ObjectType type, int index, System.Drawing.Color color)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case ObjectType.Car:
                if (index <= this.cars.Length)
                {
                    if (index != 0)
                    {
                        this.cars[index - 1].Paint(color);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var car in this.cars)
                        {
                            car.Paint(color);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                break;

            case ObjectType.House:
                if (index <= this.houses.Length)
                {
                    if (index != 0)
                    {
                        this.houses[index - 1].Paint(color);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var house in this.houses)
                        {
                            house.Paint(color);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                break;

            case ObjectType.Paper:
                if (index <= this.papers.Length)
                {
                    if (index != 0)
                    {
                        this.papers[index - 1].Paint(color);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        foreach (var paper in this.papers)
                        {
                            paper.Paint(color);
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                break;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

You see where this is going to. I actually have more types and more methods. Is there a way to encapsulate the treatment of the different arrays without using `IPaintable[][]`?

Comment: Such `switch` can/should be replaced by polymorphism.

Comment: This is one of the cases where interfaces or an abstract class will save you from having messy code. Make it an interface and let polymorphism do the work ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to implement an interface in common. Say `IPaintable`.

```
public interface IPaintable
{
    void Paint(System.Drawing.Color color);
}
```

Implement it in all those classes.

```
public class MyCar : IPaintable
{
    public void Paint(System.Drawing.Color color) { /* ... */ }
}

public class MyHouse : IPaintable
{
    public void Paint(Color color) { /* ... */ }
}

...
```

Then you can change the Painter's Paint method as below

```
public bool Paint(IList<IPaintable> paintables, int index, Color color)
{
    if (index < paintables.Count)
    {
        paintables[index].Paint(color);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Instead of saying which array to use, just pass the array itself.

If you find yourself finding which array to use in many places, you can introduce a method which does that for you.

```
private IList<IPaintable> GetPaintables(ObjectType type)
{
   switch (type)
    {
        case ObjectType.Car:
             return this.cars;
        case ObjectType.House:
             return this.houses;
        case ObjectType.Paper:
             return this.papers;
        default:
             throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    }
}
```

Then call it as

```
Paint(GetPaintables(ObjectType.House), index, color);
```

Remember having only one switch statement per enum in an application isn't a problem. Problem is repeatedly using the switch statement again and again. So `GetPaintables` isn't a problem in itself if that happens to be the only place where you switch over `ObjectType`.

Comment: In your `private IList<IPaintable> GetPaintables(ObjectType type)` you (silently) cast to IList<IPaintable>. This Co-variant conversion can cause run-time exception on write operation.

This means someone could write `paintables[0] = new MyHouse();`, setting a house into a MyCar[]

Comment: @KarstenGutjahr Given that we're not writing on the array It is safe. If you try to write on it, it will result in runtime exception.